# Android - Local Database (SQLite) vs internal classes (through a singleton)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, singleton

Let's think about this table:

[image]

Imagine we had a table like this stored inside a local database (SQLite) in our Android device. Android can manage databases quickly and efficiently, as far as I know.

How about creating a singleton, called *PeopleLab*, that went through each row in that table creating a corresponding class, *Person*, filling its properties with those of the table? In this particular example we would have 11 *Person* classes all managed by the *PeopleLab* singleton.

I was wondering, what is more efficient? (i.e. less time-consuming, less resources-consuming, bringing a better user experience). Accessing the local database using a CursorAdapter, or accessing the singleton *PeopleLab*?

**EDIT:**

Would the answer change if we had (say) 100 rows instead of just 11, each row containing (say) 100 properties instead of just 6?

**WHY AM I ASKING THIS?**

I am working in an Android project in which I need to connect to a Remote Database and copy all its content to a Local Database (using SQLite). This process is meant to be repeated nearly 10 times a day, since the Remote Dabase changes its content frequently.

Before starting writing code, I wanted to know if there is **any real benefit on creating both the Local Database and the Singleton** (with all the corresponding classes). My first idea was that Android would be faster managing classes than querying the local database for data. That would be the point of using a Singleton.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer. Why not populate your table with a couple thousand rows of junk data and run tests? Although, if you're trying to ship a product quickly, I'd just use the `CursorAdapter`

Comment: Thanks @Kenny. There should be an answer from a theoric perspective, I think. Before running tests (as you just suggested me) I wanted to know your opinions/experiences/ideas.

Comment: Well it depends. If you know you're not going to have more than 100 rows on screen at once, the efficiency gains will be minimal. The bottleneck of concern at that point will be SQLite itself. I've never used `CursorAdapter`, however. Hopefully someone else can offer their $.02.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. You read from a remote db into a local db and your question is the difference between using a Singleton to read the data instead of a `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: My question is: is there any real benefit "copying" the local database's contents to a singleton, and using that singleton instead of a CursorAdapter? Do we have gain any performance improvement?

Comment: Probably minimal at best. The `CursorAdapter` would most likely send the data straight into the view, but would have to copy the data somewhere along the line, which is what your singleton would do. And you'd probably write it less efficiently than the Android SDK version, which has survived many iterations. Again, the gains will be minimal (on the side of the `CursorAdapter`), so don't let this influence your design and implementation. Just go with what you will. It's nice to nickel and dime your processing power, but on contemporary devices, this concern is almost nonexistent.

Comment: Great answer, I would select it as accepted but it doesn't allow me (since it's not really in an "answer" format). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I put it as an answer so the question can be seen as answered on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: is there any real benefit "copying" the local database's contents to a singleton, and using that singleton instead of a CursorAdapter? Do we have gain any performance improvement?

Probably minimal at best. The `CursorAdapter` would most likely send the data straight into the view, but also would have to copy the data somewhere along the line, which is what your singleton would do. And you'd probably write it less efficiently than the Android SDK version, which has survived many iterations. Again, the gains will be minimal (on the side of the `CursorAdapter`), so don't let this influence your design and implementation. Just go with what you will. It's nice to nickel and dime your processing power, but on contemporary devices, this concern is almost nonexistent.